# Como fazer uma comparação entre 2 campos com data

Tags: c#, data

Olá, tenho 2 campos, 1 com a data de hoje e outro com uma data daqui a 9 dias. Preciso fazer uma comparação entre os 2 campos para saber se o campo com a segunda data é daqui a 10 dias ou menos, e exibir uma mensagem no MessageBox. Tentei fazer mas não consegui, qualquer ajuda é bem vinda. Obrigado.

Meu código:

```
txtDatahoje.Text = "02/02/2018";

txtData2.Text = "11/02/2018";
```

Comment: E qual é sua dificuldade específica?

Comment: na parte de fazer a comparação no if

Comment: Vamos tentar de novo, qual sua dificuldade **específica**?

Comment: Eu não sei como comparar os 2 campos pra saber se a data 2 é daqui a 10 dias ou menos.